# recurrence relation using Frobenius method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been posed the following question:
[image]

I've differentiated and substituted the Frobenius equation into the ODE to obtain the indicial equation and tried solving for the recurrence relation using the larger of the two indicial roots. However, i've tried to solve it many times and can't seem to get it. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. My attempt is in the image (part d)

edit 1: On another attempt, i obtained $a_{m+1} = \frac{-6a_{m-1}}{(m+1)(m+5)}$
edit 2: On yet another attempt, i obtained $a_{m+1} = \frac{-6a_{m-1}}{(m+7)(m+1)}$
edit 3: it seems edit 2 was the correct answer, now how can i find the first 3 non-zero terms if the power series depends on $a_{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The assumed solution is $y=x^6\sum_0 a_nx^n = \sum_0 a_nx^{n+6}$.

Now, $y' = \sum_0 (n+6)a_nx^{n+5}$ and $y'' = \sum_0 (n+6)(n+5)a_nx^{n+4}$

Substituting in the equation given (when converted to the normal form of the Frobenius equation - $x^2y''+x(-5)y'+6x^2y=0$), we get - 
$$\sum_0 (n+6)(n+5)a_nx^{n+6}-5\sum_0 (n+6)a_nx^{n+5}+6\sum_0 a_nx^{n+8}=0$$
$$\implies \sum_0 n(n+6)a_nx^{n+6}+6\sum_0 a_nx^{n+8}$$

Thus, collecting all powers of $x$, we get -
$$0.6.a_0=0\qquad(\text{from $x^6$})$$
$$1.7.a_1=0\qquad(\text{from $x^7$})$$
$$(n+2)(n+8)a_{n+2}+6a_n=0\qquad(\text{from $x^n$, $n\geq8$})$$

Thus, we get $$a_1=0$$
$$a_{n+2}=-\frac{6a_n}{(n+2)(n+8)}$$

Hence, we see that all terms with odd indices are $=0$, while even indices can be evaluated in terms of $a_0$.

Comment: so i have the recurrence relation $a_{m+1} = \frac{-6a_{m-1}}{(m+7)(m+1)}$ and need to find the first three non-zero terms of the series

Comment: would using your recurrence relation produce the same answer and if so, how do we determine $a_0$?

Comment: Your and my recurrence relations are identical, just with the your index shifted by $-1$ with respect to my index. Also, $a_0$ is an arbitrary constant, which is determined by the initial conditions.

Comment: im not given a initial condition, so should i just express the first three terms as $a_0 + \frac{-6a_0}{16} x^{2} + \frac{9a_0}{160} x^{4}$ ?

Comment: Yes, or more conveniently as $a_0(1-\frac{3}{8}x^2+\frac{9}{16}x^4)$, as this emphasizes that 1 independent solution of the ODE is $1-\frac{3}{8}x^2+\frac{9}{16}x^4+\cdots$

Comment: okay thanks. I've put in this answer but it says it is incorrect.. i'll try and see what i can do

Comment: Can we have any approch if we take $y=\sum_{k=0}^\Infity x^{n+k}$  ?